# Azure App Service denied access to Storage Account when using Service Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, vnet

Following the instructions on the [Azure Blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-virtual-network-integration-for-azure-storage-and-azure-sql/), I'm trying to remove public access to our Storage Account and instead have our App Service app only access it via a Service Endpoint.

The App Service and Service Plan are added to the same VNet, and I've configured the VNet on the Service Endpoint.

But the moment I switch on "Allow access from selected networks" in the storage account (and select the VNet and subnet) the web app begins to fail with 403 Forbidden when accessing storage.

[image: Allow access from selected networks]

Is this supposed to work, or what could I be missing?

Comment: Refer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9f4d8aeb-68a6-4ec1-9e11-bee2d1301792/allow-access-to-azure-storage-account-only-from-an-app-service?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview and see if that helps.

Comment: @x5657 Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AugustoBarreto Afraid not. But on another similar issue we were advised by Microsoft to make sure each of our VNets have a (globally?) unique ID. I haven't had time to try it yet, but I'm wondering if it would help here.